# Get Simple Facebook Profile Data Via PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I'm building a Facebook login feature on a web page that includes the following href value:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[myAppID]&redirect_uri=[myURL]&state=[myState]

It works great, but I'd like to include PHP in myURL that allows me to pull the basic public_profile FB info (email_address, first_name, last_name) upon login. I presume the PHP SDK is the way to do this. I've read the developer guide, but I'm unclear what I'd need FB session, etc. to pull this off.

At the end of my script, I'd just like the three data points mentioned above stored in variables. That's it. Can anyone provide a code sample? Thanks very much.

Comment: Found it here... http://metah.ch/blog/2014/05/facebook-sdk-4-0-0-for-php-a-working-sample-to-get-started/ Thanks for all your hard work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Download SDK from developers.facebook.com and upload the folder "Facebook" on your web space;
-Create a Facebook application;
-Put this code in the same folder of "Facebook":

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once('Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once('Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php');
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;

// init app with app id (APPID) and secret (SECRET)
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('EDIT THIS','EDIT THIS');

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'EDIT THIS' );

try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
  $email = $graphObject->getProperty('email');
  $firstname = $graphObject->getProperty('first_name');
  $lastname = $graphObject->getProperty('last_name');
} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl() . '">Get information</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. We just came across what looks like similar code.

Comment: @JRomeo You're welcome :) if my answer was helpful, you can mark it as accepted and/or upvote it :)